# Inverse boson operator realization of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$

Tags: lie-algebras

This is actually a homework problem.

The inverse boson operators $a^{-1}$ and $\left(a^\dagger\right)^{-1}$ are defined as
$$a^{-1} |n\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} |n+1\rangle$$
$$\left(a^\dagger\right)^{-1} |n\rangle = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} |n-1\rangle & n>0 \\
0 & n=0
\end{cases}
$$

$a^{-1}$ is in fact only right inverse of boson annihilation operator, and $\left(a^\dagger\right)^{-1}$ the left inverse of $\left(a^\dagger\right)$.

The question is how to construct a realization of Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ analogous to two boson realization of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$.

Comment: What is the two boson realization of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$? What do you mean by "analogous to"?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: $J_{+}=a_{1}^{\dagger}a_{2},\ J_{-}=a_{1}a_{2}^{\dagger},\ J_{z}=\frac{1}{2}\left(N_{1}-N_{2}\right)
 $ where $a_1$ and $a_2$ are two commuting annihilation operator.